# search sub folder with space in folder name using BASH

Tags: bash, find

I am writing a shell script that iterates through a set IMAP folders.

Given:

```
WORKPATH=/var/mail/mydomain.com/myaccount/
```

I want to list all subfolders inside.

Easy with find:

```
for SUB_FOLDER in $(find "$WORKPATH" -type d)
do
    echo "SUB_FOLDER: $SUB_FOLDER"
done
```

However: Some of these folders have space in their name such as:

```
/var/mail/mydomain.com/myaccount/.Deleted Mails/
/var/mail/mydomain.com/myaccount/.Junk Mails/
```

Which make code above print out something in the neighbourhood of:

```
SUB_FOLDER: /var/mail/mydomain.com/myaccount/.Deleted
SUB_FOLDER: Mails/
SUB_FOLDER: /var/mail/mydomain.com/myaccount/.Junk
SUB_FOLDER: Mails/
```

I have tried using the -print0 option and pipe to xargs -0, but I have had no luck. Playing with IFS did even more bad things to output than needed.

Could really use a tip how make find make only 2 tokens to the for loop instad of 4, or alternative way to iterate the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `while` loop:

```
while read SUB_FOLDER; do 
    echo "SUB_FOLDER: $SUB_FOLDER"; 
done < <(find "$WORKPATH" -type d)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was going nuts trying to debug what was going on.

Syntax on my system is slightly off compared to your example. I replaced last "<" with "$" which made my script behave a lot more the way I want.

Comment: Eh... ignore the replace "<" part. Turns out i was using /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash in my script. There are some subtle differences in behaviour there. Using bash made more bugs go away. :-)